# Image size mysteriously becomes 0 bytes after renaming

Tags: command-line, 18.04, memory-usage, jpeg

I renamed some `jpeg` image files through command line and all went perfect except one thing that some images do not have thumb nail and shows 0 bytes on checking their properties but are still getting viewed in `eog`. Moreover when I check their properties from `exiftool` and `identify`, everything seems normal. This anomaly has not caused me problem(yet) but I was wondering why were they behaving like this.

I executed following line on terminal to rename my files

`for subdir in *;do for f in $subdir/*;do mv $f  "$subdir"_150dpi_"${f:5:15}" ;done;done`

The output (not all) after `ls -l` is:

`total 90800
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  413958 Nov  9  2018 b203_150dpi_25.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  434711 Nov  9  2018 b203_150dpi_31.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  450432 Nov  9  2018 b203_150dpi_32.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  427775 Nov  9  2018 b203_150dpi_41.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  313645 Nov 12  2018 b209_150dpi_12.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  300690 Nov 12  2018 b209_150dpi_15.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  226017 Nov 12  2018 b209_150dpi_17.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  296103 Nov 12  2018 b209_150dpi_23.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  292266 Nov 12  2018 b209_150dpi_8.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  343003 Nov 12  2018 b210_150dpi_118.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  400393 Nov 12  2018 b210_150dpi_13.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 muhammad muhammad  409259 Nov 12  2018 b210_150dpi_20.jpg`

I am using ubuntu 18.06 and GNOME nautilus 3.26.4.

edit: The problematic files are now behaving okey i.e showing thumbnail and memory in file manager. But still don't know why they were behaving wrongly before or behaving correctly now? May be nautilus takes some time to show image thumbnail and its size.

Comment: The output for memory is also looked normal when checked from `ls  -l`

Comment: You mean the file properties from `eog` ? Seems it generated thumbs and information right in the moment when the file was created but not yet written to it and it doesn't notice if that changes. On removing `eog` cache and cleaning thumbnails it should work again.

Comment: From `eog` , I meant that they were getting displayed in Gnome image viewer.